# How do you counteract spider webs?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

They are sooo sticky.  And gross.  And seeming impossible to counteract.

In Nightmare, the spiders drop down and cover both me and anything that I build in spiderwebs, causing extreme slowness and basically negating all of the hopes and dreams I had of defending the crystals.

Is there any way to counteract them?  Some sort of stat boost or armor that negates them?
Or is it a necessary evil that I must figure out a way to avoid?

Comment: Does this question make anyone else think they should check out dungeon defenders again? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necessary evil I'm afraid.  There is no stat that reduces their effectiveness.

The best defense that I've found is more complete, tiered tower coverage.  If you tier your towers such that you have your main line, and then longer range towers with their backs to walls or cliffs covering the empty space between the crystals and your main line, then they don't have any empty space to run amok.  Of course this changes per map, tower setup, and toon, but I've found that Deadly Striker towers and some Huntress bombs/mines are especially good at dealing with them so you're more free to roam unmolested.  :)

I'm definitely interested in hearing any other strategies for dealing with them as well!

Comment: Not sure but the bowling ball towers seem to be/could be effective.  And hilarious.

Comment: While they are hilarious, they're a tough choice because of their narrow area of effect, imo. :)

Comment: yes there definitely needs to be a lane for the bowling balls otherwise you just have to hope for bouncing.  Probably not the ideal tower.

Comment: At range, harpoons do well, especially if (as @opedog said) you have them covering each other.